# codeigniter form edit bug fix

Tags: forms, codeigniter

In Codeigniter, while form editing, if any error happens in any field, then after the form submit it appears new entry in database instate of update. how can i fix it?

here is my controller code:
item() method is for editing a page.

```
function item() {       
    //pre process for edit
    $page_id = $this -> uri -> segment(3);

    if ($page_id != false) {

        //check for valid package id
        $page_q = $this -> customer_code_m -> get_by_id($page_id);

        if ($page_q -> num_rows() != 0) {

            // valid package id
            $page_data = $page_q -> row();
            $data['page_data'] = $page_data;
        } else {
            // fake package id
            redirect("welcome");
        }
    }

    $this -> load -> view('customer_code_v', $data);
}
```

process() method is for page submission.

```
function process() {                
    //pre process for edit
    $page_id = $this -> input -> post('ID');

    //echo "PAGE ID:".$page_id;
    if ($page_id != false) {

        //check for valid page id
        $page_q = $this -> customer_code_m -> get_by_id($page_id);

        if ($page_q -> num_rows() != 0) {
            // valid page id
            $page_data = $page_q -> row();
        } else {
            // fake page id
            redirect("welcome");
        }
    }

    //loading form validation
    $this -> load -> library('form_validation');

    //seting valiadtion rules
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('CustomerCode', 'Code Of Customer', 'trim|required|prep_for_form');       
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Name_Of_Customer', 'Name Of Customer', 'trim|required|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Name_Of_Customer_BN', 'Name Of Customer Bangla', 'trim|required|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Name_Of_Propritor', 'Name Of Propritor', 'trim|required|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Name_Of_Propritor_BN', 'Name Of Propritor Bangla', 'trim|required|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Address', 'Address', 'trim|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Address_BN', 'Address Bangla', 'trim|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Phone', 'Phone', 'trim|integer|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Fax', 'Fax', 'trim|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Mobile', 'Mobile', 'trim|integer|required|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Email', 'Email', 'trim|valid_email|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Division', 'Division', 'trim|required|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Area', 'Area', 'trim|required|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Zone', 'Zone', 'trim|required|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Type_Of_Party', 'Type Of Party', 'trim|required|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Gener_Of_Party', 'Gener Of Party', 'trim|required|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Grade_Of_Party', 'Grade Of Party', 'trim|required|prep_for_form');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Status', 'Status', 'trim|prep_for_form');

    if ($this -> form_validation -> run() == FALSE) {
        $this->item();
    } else {
        $form_data = array('CustomerCode' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('CustomerCode')), 'Name_Of_Customer' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Name_Of_Customer')), 'Name_Of_Customer_BN' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Name_Of_Customer_BN')), 'Name_Of_Propritor' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Name_Of_Propritor')), 'Name_Of_Propritor_BN' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Name_Of_Propritor_BN')), 'Address' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Address')), 'Address_BN' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Address_BN')), 'Phone' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Phone')), 'Fax' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Fax')), 'Mobile' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Mobile')), 'Email' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Email')), 'Division' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Division')), 'Area' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Area')), 'Zone' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Zone')), 'Type_Of_Party' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Type_Of_Party')), 'Gener_Of_Party' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Gener_Of_Party')), 'Grade_Of_Party' => htmlspecialchars($this -> input -> post('Grade_Of_Party')));

        if ($this -> input -> post('Status') == 1) {
            $form_data['Status'] = 1;
        } else {
            $form_data['Status'] = 0;
        }

        $data['form_data'] = $form_data;

        if (!empty($page_data)) {
            $form_data['page_id'] = $page_data -> ID;
            $this -> customer_code_m -> update($form_data);
            //set msg
            $this -> session -> set_flashdata('page_msg', '<p class="form_msg">Successfully updated.</p>');
            redirect("customer_code/details_item/" . $page_data -> ID);
            //print_r($form_data);
        } else {

            $this -> customer_code_m -> create($form_data);
            //set msg
            $this -> session -> set_flashdata('page_msg', '<p class="form_msg">Successfully created.</p>');
            redirect("customer_code/all");
            //print_r($form_data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The form shouldn't be submitted, if there is error. Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: my problem is, I handle the exception for every field with form_error('fieldname') at my view. but while at edit page submitting if i miss any require field the error happens as usual but I lost the page_id and that's why while I try to submit the form again it creates a new page id and a new submission at database. Now my question is how can I save my page_id for a that specific submission?

Comment: Use session. Posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem, you should save your page_id in a session variable. You can start a session with

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Then save the page_id like this

```
$this->session->set_userdata('page_id', $this->input->post('ID'));
```

For rest of the code, you use the session variable like this

```
$this->session->userdata('page_id');
```

**EDIT:**

Using `flashdata` will only keep session alive for one request. Saving session data in a database is totally different thing. In your case, there is no need to use flashdata, but saving data in a session table is better security practice as normally session is saved in cookie. You can use that. This is applied in both case whether you use `flashdata` or normal session. These two things got mixed up in my comments. I hope you are clear now.

Comment: if i use $this->session->set_flashdata('page_id', $this->input->post('ID')) will it a problem or any other security issue by using set_userdata() ?

Comment: It will save data in database, you have to create table to make it work. Check `saving session data in database` section: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: no my question was, I am creating a session. so if i use session->set_flashdata("---"), will it work like same?

Comment: Its better for security, but only last for one request. So, no need to unset as it will be automatically deleted after one request. You have to use `$this->session->set_flashdata()` for setting and `$this->session->flashdata()` for reading. To keep it for more than one request use `$this->session->keep_flashdata()`. Check the manual and try it yourself for better understand it. But don't forget to create `ci_sesssion` table.

Comment: Use `keep_flashdata` so that even if error happens the data is not lost like your post data which defeats the whole purpose of using it. Though I'd say using flashdata is not really a necessity for this case. But again, it never hurts to be prepared.